# Can werewolves die of old age?

Tags: werewolf

A werewolf can recover from wounds that would be fatal to a human being, so it can be said they could suffer an unnaturaly long life span. If they aren't hunted down and killed by angry villagers, can a werewolf die of old age?

Comment: Which universe/canon?

Comment: @DVK This is a question seeking answers or examples from the broad spectrum of werewolf mythology.

Comment: This question triggered a discussion in chat, [starting here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3510917#3510917). I'm closing as not constructive, since each author can decide that his werewolves will die for however much he likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends entirely on canon. I have seen different ranges, from:

- 10 years from the date of conversion ([Mercedes Thompson Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mercedes_Thompson_Series))
- Normal human lifespan
- Triple human lifespan seems to be a common trope
- I've never heard of immortal werewolves, but Underworld's original one, William Corvinus, survived for 800 years fully intact, with seemingly no food/water to boot. There are implications that people with Corvinus Strain are immortal, but no proof AFAIK.

Comment: Werewolves in the Mercedes Thompson series are immortal.  10 years is just an average lifespan before another werewolf kills them in a fight.  Also, old werewolves tend to go crazy and have to be killed.  But Bran is at least 1300 and still looks like a teenager.

Comment: William Corvinus lived for about 1600 years. No one with an active Corvinus Strain has died of old age or even visibly aged past about 30 in over 1600 years. The werewolves in Underworld are immortal.